# useValues is not a function, react-native-redash

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-redash

After upgrading `react-native-redash` from 9.6.0 to 15.11.1, I can't find `useValues` anymore. Has it been removed? Is there a new preferred way to get animated values?

Comment: @Tim, sure np :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [github readme](https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-redash) it is written under "V1 Users", that you can import old functions from v1 via:

```
import { useValues } from  "react-native-redash/lib/module/v1";
```

**Update December 2022.**

Since version 17.0.0 v1 version is not supported anymore. The Last compatible version is 16.3.0. You can use this version from GitHub as well.

Comment: This path does not exists anymore unfortunately on version 18.0.0

Comment: We need another fix

Comment: What did you guys end up using ? -- can I switch to using useSharedValue .. not sure its a lazy ref